# Where should I call TDSSessionManager.Instance.AddSessionEvent?

Tags: delphi, session, events, tracking, datasnap

I try to track the session creation/destruction for debugging reasons. A lot of sites cite Mat DeLong's code to handle TDSSessionManager.Instance.AddSessionEvent, see, for instance, document http://mathewdelong.wordpress.com/category/rad-studio/xe2/, scroll halfway down to the "Session Management" chapter.

There it reads ...

```
TDSSessionManager.Instance.AddSessionEvent(
  procedure(Sender: TObject; const EventType: TDSSessionEventType;
                    const Session: TDSSession)
  begin
    case EventType of
      SessionCreate: (* session was created *);
      SessionClose: (* session was closed *);
  end;
end);
```

Seems like beeing used to old style Pascal I have missed some of the new language constructus OOP added.

TDSSessionManager is a type, not an actual object. How can someone call code in a type? I would have expected something like

```
var SessionManager : TDSSessionManager;

begin
SessionManager := TDSSessionManager.Create;
...

SessionManager.AddSessionEvent(MySessionHandler);
end;
```

But wait. I have meanwhile read more about the "Singleton" TDSSessionManager. There can be only one object of this type, so TDSSessionManager.Instance can point to only one real object, I named it "SessionManager", and this is how it works. Is this theory true?

the second arcane thing is how he put the code of his event handler right into the parameter section of the caller. I would have expected something like

```
Procedure MySessionHandler(Sender: TObject; const EventType: TDSSessionEventType;
                const Session: TDSSession)
begin
case EventType of
  SessionCreate: (* session was created *);
  SessionClose: (* session was closed *);
end;
end;
```

....

```
Procedure StartMyServer;

begin
...
TDSSessionManager.Instance.AddEventHandler(MySessionHandler);
...
end;
```

Would this be possible and equivalent to DeLong's code?

Thanks for more info

Armin.

Comment: There are a few obvious places to try, such as the form's or data module's `OnCreate` event handler. Which other places have you tried that *didn't* work?

Comment: Hi Rob, TDSSessionManager is part of the REST Datasnap ecosystem, and I am talking about REST datasnap applications. Sorry, I didn't menton this in my first post.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't quite see how your response has addressed the question I asked. Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi Rob,TDSSessionManager.Instance.ForEachSession(
  procedure(const Session: TDSSession)
  begin
    //handle Session instance
  end);

Comment: What is it about that piece of code that's giving you trouble? Do you not know where to call it? Where have you tried? Or do you know how to handle the session instance? That doesn't seem to have anything to do with your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is as you think: the anonymous method can be rewritten to an 'old-school' method.

The only thing which must be considered is that the method signature

```
procedure(Sender: TObject; const EventType: TDSSessionEventType;
                    const Session: TDSSession)
```

looks like it has to be a method of a class, not a normal procedure. (To verify this check the signature of AddSessionEvent). So it would look like this:

```
procedure TSomeOutherClass.MySessionHandler(Sender: TObject; 
            const EventType: TDSSessionEventType; const Session: TDSSession)         
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: The Description is like follows:

TDSSessionEvent = reference to procedure(Sender: TObject;
const EventType: TDSSessionEventType;
const Session: TDSSession);

no trace of class methods --> I guess an ordinary "procedure" shoud do nicely.